# Display odds from database table like they are in bookmaker sites

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table odds where

```
MATCH_ID | HOME_ID |Away_ID | Group_name | Line_name      | Odd |
3000     | 1       | 2      | 1x2        | Chelsea        | 1.4
3000     | 1       | 2      | 1x2        | Liverpool      | 2.8
3000     | 1       | 2      | Handicap   | Chealse - 1.5  | 2.9
3000     | 1       | 2      | Handicap   | Liverpool +1.5 | 1.4
```

every match has **odds** related to this match.

How i could get the odds listed like they are on bookmaker websites like Bet365 when you click on some event and they are grouped and related?

**Expected output:**

[image]

**Thank you!**

As you can see in the picture "**To Win**" would be **1x2** on my table.

As well as Point Betting would be Handicap

Comment: Add an example of your expected result.

Comment: Your table should have column names. And you should also be showing the result that you expect, along with your current attempt. Finally, are you looking for a pure SQL solution or for something in lavarel?

Comment: Please check the image, i added the result i would like to get from table. Im asking for your ideas on this. Maybe the best SQL which i could possibly write and then do all sorting on php side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to group your results by 'Group_name' column.
e.g.
`->where('MATCH_ID', 3000)->get()->groupBy('Group_name')`
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-groupby

Comment: I have done that but then im getting only the first team odd lines.

Comment: Yes, it works like a charm! Just needed to dd($odds);